# SSIS - How to configure Error Output to show all columns or redirected rows?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I need Error Output coming from the Flat File Source to show all columns of any redirected row, not just the ErrorCode or ErrorColumn columns. Advanced Editor at the Flat File Source gives me an error when I try to add output columns to Error Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this: you have a source component. It is responsible for generating data by parsing source row. An error has happened such that it couldn't split the data for that row. If the parse worked, then you could have individual columns but it failed so all that you can do is access the whole row because that's the only thing that exists.